# Installing Java 3D on Windows using zipped archive

Tags: installation, java-3d

I am trying to install Java 3D 1.5.2 on Windows manually using a zipped archive available from [here](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/builds/release/1.5.2/). The installation instructions in the README-unzip.html file within the archive are as follows:

> Windows
>
> The 1.5.2 release of the Java 3D API for Windows 2000, Windows XP (x86
> or amd64), and Windows Vista runs on JDK version 1.5.0 and higher. To
> manually install this release, do the following:
>
> 1. Download and unzip j3d-1_5_2-XXX.zip (using Windows Explorer or an
>    unzip tool such as WinZip) to a temporary download folder, for
>    example, c:\Downloads. This will create a j3d-1_5_2-XXX subfolder in
>    your download folder where the downloaded files can be found. The file
>    you need for manual installation is j3d-jre.zip.
> 2. Create a folder for the j3d jar files and native libraries, for
>    example, C:\Users\myhome\j3d, and unzip j3d-jre.zip into this folder.
> 3. Modify your CLASSPATH environment variable to include the full paths
>    to j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, and vecmath.jar. For example, add the
>    following to your CLASSPATH variable, using the System control panel,
>    Advanced tab, Environment Variables button:
>
> > ;C:\Users\myhome\j3d\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Users\myhome\j3d\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\User > s\myhome\j3d\lib\ext\vecmath.jar
>
> 4.Modify your PATH environment variable to contain the full path to the
> lib\i386 folder (or lib\amd64 for Windows/x64). For example, on 32-bit
> Windows, add the following to your PATH variable, using the System
> control panel, Advanced tab, Environment Variables button.
>
> C:\Users\myhome\j3d\lib\i386
>
> At this point your Java installation
> should be able to see the j3d class files. Users of IDEs such as
> NetBeans and Eclipse should consult the IDE's documentation to see how
> to add jar files and native libraries to their current project.

According to step 4, I add a folder called 'i386' in lib folder to the PATH variable. However, no such folder exists in lib folder ! What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the j3d\bin folder to your PATH variable.

It should contain DLL files that are either 32-bit or 64-bit, with names like j3d-ogl.dll.

I wrote a .exe that installs Java3D 1.5.2 in addition to Java 6 SDK. The source is at this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/hmartiro/princeton-java-installers) if you want to have a look - it is written in PowerShell. The 64-bit Java 3D is downloaded from [j3d64.zip](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/j3d64.zip). The 32-bit is in the same place with a 32 suffix instead of 64.

Here is the relevant snippet of the installation log that details the steps taken:

```
#### Step 2 - Java3D ###############################################

Downloading Java3D from
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/j3d64.zip
to
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d.zip

Extracting zip archive in place at
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d.zip
and deleting .zip file.

Setting the user PATH environment variable to include
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d\bin

Setting the user CLASSPATH environment variable to include
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d\lib\ext\vecmath.jar

Setting the user CLASSPATH environment variable to include
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar

Setting the user CLASSPATH environment variable to include
C:\Users\username\introcs\j3d\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar
```